# Compiler Error {-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

I try to compile EnglishAuction.hs code in playground web app and keep on getting compiler error.

"[compiler] [E] loadObj "/nix/store/jmhwwzn1yfjzlxavz16afkf1r4shmp8z-
persistent-sqlite-lib-persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.3/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.10.4.
20210212/persistent-sqlite-2.13.0.3-8rnIaulr0SMFWDeiU7TZN4/HSpersistent-
sqlite-2.13.0.3-8rnIaulr0SMFWDeiU7TZN4.o": failed"

Answer (score 3):

I just removed the module section of the code in EnglishAuction.hs and paste it into playground web. It work and no compiler error.

module Week01.EnglishAuction
( Auction (..)
, StartParams (..), BidParams (..), CloseParams (..)
, AuctionSchema
, start, bid, close
, endpoints
, schemas
, ensureKnownCurrencies
, printJson
, printSchemas
, registeredKnownCurrencies
, stage
) where